# Passing an object to a switch statement to be passed to a method in different class

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, switch-statement

I'm trying to pass the object that is in case `A` to case `G` and I'm trying to get it to pass to the method `addGameDetails()` that is in the `HockeyPlayer` class

So that the player in case `A` that I have added can get details about them.

```
package hockeyplayer;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HockeyPlayer {

    private final int[] goals = new int[10];
    private final String[] teamName = new String[10];
    private final int[] gameNumber = new int[10];
    private int[] game = new int[10];
    private static String name;
    private static int playerNumber;

    public HockeyPlayer() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int goalsScored = -1;
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the player");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the player number 1-12");
        playerNumber = input.nextInt();

    }

    public int[] getGoals() {
        return goals;
    }

    public String[] getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public int[] getGameNumber() {
        return gameNumber;
    }

    public int[] getGame() {
        return game;
    }

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static int getPlayerNumber() {
        return playerNumber;
    }

    public void setGame(int[] game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public static void setName(String name) {
        HockeyPlayer.name = name;
    }

    public static void setPlayerNumber(int playerNumber) {
        HockeyPlayer.playerNumber = playerNumber;
    }



    public void addGameDetails() {
        HockeyPlayer firstPlayer = new HockeyPlayer();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the game number");
        gameNumber [0] = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What team was it against?");
        teamName[0] = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many goals was scored by "+name+"?");
        goals[0] = input.nextInt();


    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String output = "";

        return output;
    }

}
```

---

```
package hockeyplayer;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HockeyPlayerMain {

    private static HockeyPlayer[] player = new HockeyPlayer[12];

    private static final String MENU = "***Hockey Tracker***\n"
            + "A- Add player details\n"
            + "G- Add game details\n"
            + "S- Show players \n"
            + "X- Exit\n";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String option = "";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println(MENU);
            option = input.nextLine();
            switch (option) {
                case "A":
                    HockeyPlayer p = new HockeyPlayer();
                    player[p.getPlayerNumber() - 1] = p;

                    break;

                case "G":

                    break;

                case "S":

            }

        } while (!option.equalsIgnoreCase("X"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Maintain a reference to the last player you created in `A` as local variable in `main`, just don't forget to check to see if the `lastPlayer` is no `null` before you try and get information from it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to addGameDetails for any HockeyPlayer, that you want you could ask for playerNumber like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String option = "";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println(MENU);
        option = input.nextLine();
        switch (option) {
            case "A":
                HockeyPlayer p = new HockeyPlayer();
                player[p.getPlayerNumber() - 1] = p;

                break;

            case "G":
                int playerId = Integer.valueOf(input.nextLine());
                player[playerId-1].addGameDetails();
                break;

            case "S":

        }

    } while (!option.equalsIgnoreCase("X"));

}
```

or if you want to pass only the last added you can just save reference:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String option = "";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    HockeyPlayer lastAdded = null; 

    do {
        System.out.println(MENU);
        option = input.nextLine();
        switch (option) {
            case "A":
                HockeyPlayer p = new HockeyPlayer();
                player[p.getPlayerNumber() - 1] = p;
                lastAdded = p;
                break;

            case "G":
                if (lastAdded != null) lastAdded.addGameDetails();
                break;

            case "S":

        }

    } while (!option.equalsIgnoreCase("X"));

}
```